# Multidimensional array to individual variables

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array, variable-assignment

I have a multidimensional array like this, which is a set of latitudes and longitudes.

```
multi = [[12.96145, 77.58408],[12.96219, 77.58447],[12.96302, 77.58489],[12.96316, 77.58496],[12.96348, 77.58511],[12.96356, 77.58512],[12.96363, 77.5851],[12.96372, 77.58506],[12.96376, 77.58497],[12.96374, 77.58479]]
```

I want to convert the above array into individual variables like below:

```
lat1 = 12.96145
lon1 = 77.58408
lat2 = 12.96219
lon2 = 77.58447
.
.
```

I tried to achieve the above by a lengthy procedure like below. And I hope there will be definitely a better way to do this.

```
l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8,l9,l10 = multi

lat1 = l1.first
lon1 = l1.last
lat2 = l2.first
lon2 = l2.last
.
.
```

Comment: Why not just call from the array? Isn't that a lot easier?

Comment: @c650 sorry I didn't get your point. If you give me little more hint I will definitely try to achieve.

Comment: Instead of putting each value into a variable, why not just call directly from the array?

Comment: @c650 thanks for the valuable suggestion.But my requirement is little different.I think I need separate values. 

As I want to pass a line string to a custom sql query in rails app, sql query is like `sql = "SELECT st_astext(ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(foo.the_line, ST_Line_Locate_Point(foo.the_line, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(#{lat} #{lon})')))) as g FROM (SELECT ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(#{lat1} #{lon1},#{lat2} #{lon2}, #{lat3} #{lon3}, #{lat4} #{lon4}, #{lat5} #{lon5})') As the_line) As foo;"`. I feel accepted answer is work for my requirement. Will other method works for my above query?

Comment: Now I'm wondering why you aren't using ActiveRecord...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lat1, lon1,
lat2, lon2,
...
latn, lonn,
= multi.flatten
```

or

```
(lat1, lon1),
(lat2, lon2),
...
(latn, lonn),
= multi
```

Answer (score 1):

Also may assign values to instance variables like this:

```
  multi.each_with_index do |pair, i|
    instance_variable_set("@lat#{i%multi.size+1}", pair.first)
    instance_variable_set("@lon#{i%multi.size+1}", pair.last)
  end
```

Then refer to variables so: `@lat1`, `@lon1`, ..., `@latn`, `@lonn`